# Remove Default Domain Viewer from File in Google Drive

Tags: google-apps-script

I am working on a very simple script that will update the viewers of a document. In my Google Apps domain, the default sharing permissions were changed. My admin would like to go back and change the sharing settings on all existing documents. While working on my POC, I have encountered an error and was wondering if there was a different piece of GAS which I should employ.

The problem is that I am unable to remove the domain user as a viewer on a document due to an "Invalid Email" error.

The message is: `Exception: Invalid email: MyDomain.com`

Thank you in advance for any assistance.

[I have removed logging and error catching from the following code.]

```
function removeDomainUser()
{
  DocsList.getAllFiles().forEach(
    function (file,i ,array)
    {

        //--Always pick the Domain Viewer--//

        var toRemove = -1;
        file.getViewers().forEach(
          function(user,i)
          {
            toRemove = user.getEmail() == "MyDomain.com" ? i : toRemove;
          }
        );

        //--If there is a Domain viewer, remove it--//

        toRemove > -1 ? file.removeViewer(file.getViewers()[toRemove]) : '';
    }
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately this isn't possible using the DocsList service. There is an [open feature request](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=904) to add this functionality. You should be able to accomplish this by making calls to the [Documents List API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/) using UrlFetchApp.

Comment: Thank you. I'll have to make this retro fit using the API (which I half expected, but wanted to make sure I wasn't doing something wrong).

Answer (score 0):

I havent figured out the error in your code but I have been able to achieve the same goal with the following bit of code

```
function removeDomainUser(user){
  //User is your domain user
  // e.g user = email@mydomain.com
  var files = DocsList.getAllFiles();
  for(var i in files){
    var viewvers = files[i].getViewers();
    for(var j in viewvers){
      if(viewvers[j] == user) files[i].removeViewer(user);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: There is no error in the functionality of my code. If I grab a user such as "me@mydomain.com," then that user is removed. Functionally, your code is the same as mine.

The problem I am having is with the default viewer set by having the Apps sharing default set to:

**This organization**
People at this organization can find and access.

Hopefully this helps:
`DocsList.getAllFiles()[0].getViewers()[0].getEmail()` returns: "MyDomain.com"
but,
`var userToRemove = DocsList.getAllFiles()[0].getViewers()[0];`
`DocsList.getAllFiles()[0].removeViewer(userToRemove)` throws the error in my question.